# Dragging, Dropping & resizing elements

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web page which has three `<div>` elements:

`Right_bar` contains several layouts (nothing to do with this question)

`Bottom_bar` contains several components e.g. calculator, logo, a group of buttons etc. each component uses a `<div>` and must be resizable and draggable.

And a Working Area, where all the components are dropped & resized. Also a user can resize & change the location of components anywhere in the Working Area. **Once a user sets a component then the page must be saved in same style and it shouldn't be changed even after refreshing the page.**

My questions are:

1. Should I use a database to save the location of component.
2. Which one should I use: JQuery / AJAX / anyother?

If you know of any tutorials please let me know although I am beginner in JavaScript, Basically a Java programmer.

Note: on the server side I am using Servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What you can do is save the location of the control in a xml and save it in a table.

2.jquery UI has as build in framework that supports drag and drop div elements, check this link http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: Thanks Cliffc, I just went through this JQuery link and it simply tells about the dragging & dropping but whenever you refresh the page elements goes back to it's origin location.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the user drops an element, launch a simple Ajax request that will pass the new value to the server.

```
try {
   var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE
}
catch(e)
{
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Other browsers
}
xmlhttp.open('GET', 'yourServerScript.url?param=value', true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
```

You may want to check if the request succeeded or failed by handling the "readystatechange" event of your http request, but that doesn't seem important in your case.
After that you just have to get the value server-side, store it in a session variable, and then on every page load, check if there is a session variable defined for the parameter before setting it to its default value.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing for an application. (but I used PHP, anyway it doesn't matter for what you need)

1. I used jQuery + jQuery UI drag & drop / resize
2. I used AJAX with 4 parameters (x,y, z-index and id of the element) for drag & drop on [drag stop](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop)
3. I used XML as a database for this, but any database (or any persistance way) will do the trick. As @Thibault Witzig said, take the most pertinent for your project.

Comment: Why do you want to save this to a database ? This is not important information, only display settings. Session + Cookie if long-time persistance is needed looks fine.

Comment: Because, in my case, I needed the changes to be saved everywhere I go. Session was too short, cookies save only on **one** computer; if you go on another, the display will be the default one. The persistance depends on the project and its goal.

Comment: I'd use a database for this - it's expandable to multiple users and is probably faster than XML parsing.

Comment: @JamWaffles : Totally agree, that's why I told the OP about database (w/o naming one since I don't use JAVA). For my project, there was only one user and the server only had PHP and no DB, XML was my choice and worked well.